# What are off-the-shelf chicken burger patties made of?

Tags: chicken, hamburgers

I bought some burder patties from the supermarket.

The price is very cheap. However, they don't look or smell like chicken.

Packaging says the following:

> Mechanically separated chicken meat (55.5%), water, chicken skins, wheat starch, onion, salt, soy protein, semolina ( wheat ), rapeseed oil, aromas, spice extracts, dextrose, thickener (carrageenan), spices ( mustard ), vegetable protein hydrolyzate ( soy ), flavor enhancer (monosodium glutamate), stabilizers (tara gum, xanthan gum), acidity regulator (potassium chloride), black pepper, antioxidant (sodium isoascorbate), preservative (sodium nitrite)
> Allergens: Gluten, Mustard, Soy

What are off-the-shelf chicken burger patties made of?

Comment: Well, what does the ingredients list say?

Comment: Your ingredients clearly state what the patties are made of, so there doesn't seem to be a question to answer. If you have a question about one of the ingredients please edit and make that clear, otherwise it makes no sense to keep this question open.

Answer (score 1):

You can just google your first key ingredient, namely [mechanically separated meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanically_separated_meat) (wikipedia). It is an industrial process where chicken pieces (usually the carcasses left over after removing the large meat pieces like the breasts) are finely ground and then pressed through a sieve to separate the bones from the remainder. It is quite unlike what you would get if you just grind up a chicken breast but it is perfectly save to eat.